# Apply "live" css with jquery to many tags with same class indepedently

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, each, mousemove

I have on my stage 8 pupils that move in interaction with the mouse cursor. I can'T figure out how to apply the css to each independently. Can someone help me out on this one?

Here's the code

```
jQuery(function($){

    /*I have 8 pupils in total*/
    $("body").mousemove(function(event) {
        var eye = $(".pupil");
        var x = (eye.offset().left) + (eye.width() / 2);
        var y = (eye.offset().top) + (eye.height() / 2);
        var rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
        var rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
        

        /*I can't figure out how to fix the -for each-*/
        $(eye).each(function() {
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'});
        });

    });
});
```

And here's the jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NickBil/qaspfk1L/2/

Comment: ```$(".pupil")``` is an array, you should iterate over it. This would help: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: thanks, gonna take a good look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery it helps to think on the basis of sets or lists. Your instinct was right but you applied it slightly incorrectly. So instead of

```
jQuery(function($){

  /*I have 8 pupils in total*/
  $("body").mousemove(function(event) {
    var eye = $(".pupil");
    var x = (eye.offset().left) + (eye.width() / 2);
    var y = (eye.offset().top) + (eye.height() / 2);
    var rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
    var rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;


    /*I can't understand how to fix the -for each-*/
    $(eye).each(function() {
      $(this).css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'});
    });

  });
});
```

Try more like this

```
jQuery(function($){

        /*I have 8 pupils in total*/
        $("body").mousemove(function(event) {
        
            $(".pupil").each(function() {
              var eye = $(this);
              var x = (eye.offset().left) + (eye.width() / 2);
              var y = (eye.offset().top) + (eye.height() / 2);
              var rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
              var rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
            
              $(this).css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'});

        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand the approach now  :)